# Use shell script to select a specific pdf with unique filename format and recent creation-date?

Tags: bash, text-processing, filenames

I am needing some help with a script. I'm currently trying to select PDF file that meets a specific requirement in the file name in order to move it to a different location.

The filename format I'm trying to select from has separated sections like the example below:

```
I_XXX_PACK_6788669_6_9358869.pdf
```

What I am trying to do is select only files that have the last section in the file name (e.g. `9358869`) and ignore all others pdf files in the directory.

Can it be done with Unix tools (POSIX find, sed, grep, etc.), my main issue right now is trying to only get only the one file that was 6 separated sections in its filename and ignoring all other files.

- Also is it possible to only choose the files that were created 1hr prior to system time? I have use sed on other file types to check for time, but not on a pdf file. So I am not sure if that is possible or not

Comment: Most filesystems do not store in file meta the time of creation, so you should select different time as reference.

Comment: Is the creation time encoded in the file name or stored in the file contents? If so, what is that mapping? If not, would last modification time work instead of creation time? When you say "Can this be done with bash only" do you mean can it be done with just bash builtins or do you mean can it be done with mandatory Unix tools (POSIX find, sed, grep, etc.) called from a bash script, or do you mean with GNU coreutils tools called from a bash script or something else? Please [edit] your question to provide answers and show your attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '[!_]*_*_*_*_*_*[!_].pdf' ! -name '*_*_*_*_*_*_*' ! -name '*__*'
```

Would report the files (of any type¹) whose name ends in `.pdf` and contains 5 and only 5 `_` characters and where each of the `_`-separated parts of the root name is not empty.

With some `find` implementations, files whose name cannot be decoded as text in the current locale will also be excluded.

To limit to those last modified within the last hour, as Chris says, the `-newermt '1 hour ago'`, `-mmin 60` or `-mtime -1m` supported by some implementations are not standard and POSIX `find` has no equivalent other than `-newer some-file-with-a-last-modification-time-one-hour-ago`.

The usual way to create one search reference time in a POSIX way is to do:

```
TZ=XXX0 touch -t "$(TZ=XXX1 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" some-file-with-a-last-modification-time-one-hour-ago
```

Where `date` is called in a timezone (which we name `XXX` though the name is irrelevant here) which we defined as being one hour behind UTC and `touch` interprets the timestamp produced by `date` as if it was UTC time (in a timezone also called `XXX` but which is 0 hour behind UTC) so ends up creating a one hour old file.

After which you can do:

```
find . -name '[!_]*_*_*_*_*_*[!_].pdf' \
       ! -name '*_*_*_*_*_*_*' \
       ! -name '*__*' \
       -newer some-file-with-a-last-modification-time-one-hour-ago
```

If as your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag suggests, you're not constrained to using POSIX `sh` syntax, then you could use `zsh` instead where all that can be done without the need of any external utility:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/([^_]##_)(#c5)_[^_]##.pdf(ND-.mh-1)
```

Where:

- `**/` matches any level of subdirectories (including 0)
- `[^_]` matches any character other than `_`
- `x##` matches one or more `x`es, same as `x(#c1,)`.
- `x(#c5)` matches exactly 5 `x`es
- `N`ullglob expands to nothing if there's no match instead of reporting an error.
- `D`otglob includes hidden ones
- `.` and `mh-1` regular files and last modified less than one hour ago (or in the future), and `-` for that check to be done after symlink resolution.
- `print -rC1 --` `print`s its arguments `r`aw and on `1` `C`olumn.

If you want to restrict the match to those files where the last 3 parts have to be decimal integer numbers, you can change it to:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/([^_]##_)(#c3)<->_<->_<->.pdf(ND-.mh-1)
```

Where `<->` is the `<1-20>` form of number matching operator but here without boundaries so matches any decimal integer number (any sequence of one or more ASCII decimal digits which you could also write `[0-9]##`).

---

<sup>¹ you could add `-type f` to only consider the files of type *regular* (as opposed to fifos, devices, directories, pipes...) but note that it would also exclude symlinks to regular files. To include those, you'd need `-xtype f`, but that's also a non-standard (GNU) extension.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, This worked the best when I was testing it. I still need to verfiy this part  "-newer some-file-with-a-last-modification-time-one-hour-ago"

If you like I can show the code that I will be using

Comment: I was looking at the TZ= approach with date and touch but I ended up running round in ever decreasing circles. Does your approach work for timezones that are away from GMT?

Comment: @ChrisDavies, that's completely independent from the user's timezone. The user's timezone is not seen by either `date` nor `touch` as we define `TZ` for both, and those `TZ` are only intended as a tool to create a one hour old file. That's totally independent from any outside timezone. A file one hour in the past is a file one hour in the past regardless of what that timestamp looks like in the user's timezone. That's why I use `XXX` to make it clear that where on the globe those timezones may be relevant if at all is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3):

You have files such as `I_XXX_PACK_6788669_6_9358869.pdf` and you want only those that match six `_`-separated sections with the last one being `9358869`.

This will match at least six `_`-separated sections (the `*` is a wildcard that matches zero or more characters, including `_`) ending with `9358869.pdf`:

```
*_*_*_*_*_9358869.pdf
```

You can look for files modified (but not created) within the last hour using `find`, but this extension is not POSIX:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -mmin -60
```

To allow for POSIX you need to use `-newer {file}`, having set `{file}` to an appropriate age. POSIX doesn't provide a reliable way of setting a file's modification datetime to an hour in the past, but as you've tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) we can use that:

```
printf -v curr '%(%s)T'
past=$(printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M)T\n' "$((curr - 60*60))")
touch -t "$past" /path/to/timestamp

find /path/to/directory -type f -newer /path/to/timestamp
```

Finally, merging the two:

```
touch -t "$(printf -v curr '%(%s)T'; printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M)T\n' "$((curr - 60*60))")" /path/to/timestamp
find /path/to/directory -type f -newer /path/to/timestamp -name '*_*_*_*_*_9358869.pdf'
```